# Bitbucket pipelines | Host key verification failed

Tags: bitbucket, pipeline, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

Having an issue with bitbucket pipelines, throwing `Host key verification failed.`

Bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: php:7.3.3
pipelines:
  branches:
    development:
      - step:
          name: Deploying in Development
          deployment: development
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-client
            - apt update && apt install -y unzip rsync wget
            - echo "Cloning Project" && ssh -tt $TABACK_SSH_USER@$DEV_SERVER "rm -rf $RELEASE_DIR_TMP && mkdir $RELEASE_DIR_TMP && cd $RELEASE_DIR_TMP && git clone --branch $BITBUCKET_BRANCH https://$REPO_CRED/trustanalytica/react-client.git $RELEASE_DIR_TMP"
            - echo "Copy env file" && ssh -tt $TABACK_SSH_USER@$DEV_SERVER "cp $APP_ROOT/env.$BITBUCKET_BRANCH.client $RELEASE_DIR_TMP/.env"
            - echo "Install Dependencies" && ssh -tt $TABACK_SSH_USER@$DEV_SERVER "cd $RELEASE_DIR_TMP && yarn install"
            - echo "Build" && ssh -tt $TABACK_SSH_USER@$DEV_SERVER "cd $RELEASE_DIR_TMP && yarn build"
            - echo "Deploy" && ssh -tt $TABACK_SSH_USER@$DEV_SERVER "cd $RELEASE_DIR_TMP && ./deploy.sh"
```

I have the following settings with ssh on the instance.

.ssh/config

```
Host bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

I have added my .pub key in `authorized_keys` and in `known_hosts`

```
bitbucket.org,3.136.180.187 ssh-rsa xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx abc@xxx.com
```

On the bitbucket side, the following are the repository variables

[image]

I have also added my server public IP and hostname to Known hosts in bitbucket > repository settings > pipelines > ssh keys -> known hosts.

Please note that the public and private key are generated with ssh-keygen on server itself which are id_rsa and id_rsa.pub, I then copied and pasted the public and private keys to bitbucket > repository settings > pipelines > ssh keys.

The actual exception :

[image]

*Really don't have any idea what is missing.*

Comment: You say "I have the following settings with ssh on the instance."  What instance? The remote server? A pipeline runner? Your laptop?

Comment: "I have added my .pub key in `authorized_keys` and in `known_hosts`": **your** key? Not pipeline's key? Why in `known_hosts`?

Comment: Can you print the output of `ssh $TABACK_SSH_USER@$DEV_SERVER -nv`?

Comment: Also, any reason not to use https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=atlassian/ssh-run or use any other image already featuring ssh tooling instead of `php:7`?